# Why did Dr Lapham suggest that Malorie consider putting her child up for adoption?

Tags: bird-box

Dr. Lapham speaks to Malorie:

> Dr. Lapham: But if that's not what you want, **there are plenty of
> couples who are desperate to adopt a child**. There are no judgments
> here. You can make whatever choice you want.

Why did Dr Lapham suggest that Malorie put her child up for adoption?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the [original script](https://www.scriptslug.com/assets/uploads/scripts/bird-box-2018.pdf), it was Malorie that was considering putting her child up for adoption. She's suffering from anxiety and is in a state of denial about the pregnancy. She sees an adoption leaflet and takes it from the doctor's office.

In the film they seem to have combined the two scenes to cut down on running time.

> **DR. LAPHAM:** *You’re due in twelve weeks, so let’s try some natural remedies for the insomnia before I prescribe anything.
> (casually) **You have a name picked?***
>
> **MALORIE:** ***Not yet. Something about it... It hasn’t really clicked with me. You know? The idea. Motherhood.***
>
> **DR. LAPHAM:** *That’s normal. It will pass.*
>
> Malorie smiles sadly and nods. While holding that smile:
>
> **MALORIE:** *What if it doesn’t?*
>
> Dr. Lapham reads from her clipboard.
>
> **DR. LAPHAM:** *Everything will change after the baby’s born. Now, let’s talk about
> the next trimester. Expect more weight gain, but if it gets more than forty pounds over where you were before, call me.*
>
> CREEPING IN on Malorie as she listens to the doctor, and **it all plays out on her face: A silent war against encroaching anxiety.** She looks away. Takes a breath as Lapham  continues:
>
> **DR. LAPHAM** (O.S.) (CONT’D): *Heartburn will be more common. You might also deal with hemorrhoids, discharge, bleeding, and varicose veins, that’s all natural. Be aware
> of Braxton Hicks contractions at odd hours, like tremors before a real quake...*
>
> The doctor’s voice grows more and more distant as Malorie struggles to keep it all together. And then--
>
> INT. HOSPITAL BATHROOM - MOMENTS LATER
> Malorie vomits into the toilet bowl.
> She cleans herself up at the sink and stares at herself in the mirror. Her own bloodshot eyes stare back.
> Malorie washes her face. Then goes to the towels to dry her
> face and hands.
> **Nearby: A basket of reading material. Magazines. Pamphlets.**
> **Flyers about parenthood, childbirth.**
> **Malorie notices one. Picks it up.**
> **The headline: “YOU HAVE A CHOICE. // Give your child to a good home!”**
> An informational flyer on adoption.
> Malorie considers something.
> Then puts the flyer in her purse.

Answer (score 2):

In the United States, [there are more couples looking to adopt an infant than there are infants](https://adoptionnetwork.com/adoption-myths-facts/domestic-us-statistics/) (the statistics change as a child gets older). Therefore, when faced with someone expecting a child who isn't certain that they want to raise them for whatever reason, a medical professional will often suggest adoption so that the baby is available to those parents.

In Malorie's case, she is not in a dedicated relationship, and therefore she faces additional difficulties in raising a child. I don't remember if she'd expressed ambivalence regarding that, but either way, most medical professionals want their patients to know all of their options should their decision change so that they don't feel trapped in their decision.